# my collision is not working

Tags: collision, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everyone,
I am new to gazebo, so I am not very familiar with gazebo.

My problem is about collision.
I have put on  tag in my urdf-file ( a hand model ), but the little finger still can run into my Palm.

The following is my code, and **the bottom is the video.**

is my palm,  is the little finger's first part,  is the little finger's second part.

https://gist.github.com/pythongo1/11dea9ba511ab75edcfb4ea4eba161b3

```
  
    
      
      
      
      
      
    

    
      
      
      
      
    

    
      
      
      
    
  


  
    
    
    

            
    
  

  
    
      
      
        
      
      
    

    
      
      
        
      
    

    
      
      
      
    
  

  
    
    
    

    
    
  

  
    
         
      
        
         -->
      
    

    
         
      
        
         -->
```

This is the video.

https://youtu.be/rfyfUmKTd70

Thank you for your answer.  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23813/my-collision-is-not-working/) by [danielzeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16457/danielzeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try specifying the [self collide](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=link#link_self_collide) property inside gazebo tags

```
<gazebo reference="link_name">
    <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    ...
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielzeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16457/danielzeng/) on 2019-09-26**:
Hello, sorry so late to reply to you.

I use your method, and it really works!!!

The little finger does not go into my Palm.

Thank you very much
.
You help me a lot !!